# Unable to use Datepicker in a table when inserting a row

Tags: css, javascript, jquery, html

Here is the html code for which the datepicker works-

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-4'>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date pickadate'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function for datepicker:-

```
    //Script for claendar 
$(function() {
        $('.pickadate').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            autoclose: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            orientation: "button"
        });
    });
```

The function for inserting a new row:-

```
//Inserting new row
$(document).on('click', '.btn_new_row', function(event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    //create a random id
    var row_id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);

    var user_id = <?php echo $user_id; ?>

    //get table rows
    var tbl_row = $(document).find('.tbl_code_with_mark').find('tr');    
    var tbl = '';
    tbl +='<tr row_id="'+row_id+'", user_id="'+user_id+'">';
        tbl +='<td><div class="pickadate new_row_data date editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="date"><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span></div></td>';
        tbl +='<td ><div class="new_row_data purpose editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="purpose"></div></td>';
        tbl +='<td ><div class="new_row_data category editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="category"></div></td>';
        tbl +='<td ><div class="new_row_data sum editinfo" contenteditable="true" edit_type="click" col_name="sum"></div></td>';

        //--->edit options > start
        tbl +='<td>';            
            tbl +='  <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn_new" row_id="'+row_id+'" > Add Entry</a>   | ';
            tbl +='  <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn_remove_new_entry" row_id="'+row_id+'"> Remove</a> ';
        tbl +='</td>';
        //--->edit options > end    

    tbl +='</tr>';
    tbl_row.first().after(tbl);

    $(document).find('.tbl_code_with_mark').find('tr').first().find('.purpose').focus();

});
```

The datepicker does not seem to work for the date fields in the table. I've tried almost everything but nothing seems to work. Please help!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ToYGY0jp9w Here is the link of the video from which I took up the base code.

Comment: Is there an error in the developer console?  If I’m reading this right, one date picker works, when you add a second one, none of them work?

Comment: No error in the console. When I add the second one, the first one still works.

Comment: Just to get a bit of clarification, your table output doesn't appear to have any inputs.  I'm not sure whether it's relevant but does the datepicker() function work with non-input elements.

Comment: The table shows all the inputs. Yep, it works with non-input elements.